# Remove click event animation on BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, bottomnavigationview

When I click an item in my Bottom Navigation Menu there's a "click animation". I googled but couldn't find a way to remove that animation - just the shift/scale animation. This animation is a click event like a 'drop' in water when an item is pressed. How can I disable that animation in .XML?

Here's my Bottom Navigation in the activity.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/transparent"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/transparent"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `app:itemRippleColor="@null"` to BottomNavigationView in layout xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/white"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/transparent"
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/transparent"
app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
app:itemRippleColor="@null" />
```