# Android Studio: remove highlight of BottomNaviagationView Items

Tags: android, xml, navbar, highlight

ive been trying to remove that highlight that comes up when an item in the navbar is selected.
I only want to make them items change the color on selected and unselected and i just cant get it, i tried nearly everything.

Heres my code in the main.xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            app:menu="@drawable/menu_navigation"  />
```

This is the code of the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#248f24"
        android:drawable="@color/black"/>
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="#d1d1e0"
        android:drawable="@color/design_default_color_background"/>

</selector>
```

And this is the menu navigation block

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:icon="@drawable/flameicon"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/recipes"
        android:icon="@drawable/listicon"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settingsicon"/>

</menu>
```

If anyone could help thatd be much appreciated, thank you!

Nearly everything that xml possibly can do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove click event animation on BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986279/remove-click-event-animation-on-bottomnavigationview)

Comment: Almost but the backround of the icons is still highlighted

Comment: can you give screenshot as it's working fine when tried .. also which android version you use and library versions used for material for this package ‘com.google.android.material' ?

Comment: I found out by myself but i wouldnt have done it without your help man, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute i was looking for was "app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent""